# Rendered more hooks than during the previous render - nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to get my `items' with a api call inside` useEffect`:

```
export const MyComponent = () => {


 // const cartContext = useCartContext();
  let [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    api.get('cart?detail=true').then((res: any) => {

      const result = res;
      setItems(result.gifts);

    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  });

return (

   <div className="cart-factor-items">
        {
          items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                 <div>....</div>
```

but I got this error message:

```
Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
```

Comment: you didn't show all relevant code

Comment: I think you forgot add `useEffect` dependency at the end `[]`